# INDIRECT function with language-agnostic reference string

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to reference totals from a table using a custom-created reference string. This basically works fine until I open the spreadsheet in excel been installed in different language. So what I have is:

```
INDIRECT("Attendees[[#Totals];["&[@ColumnFromMyCurrentTable]&"]]")
```

it gets translated to Polish, when I open it on another computer, so I get:

```
ADR.POŚR("Attendees[[#Totals];["&[@ColumnFromMyCurrentTable]&"]]")
```

which leads to Reference Error, since the reference string should on Polish version be: `"Attendees[[#Sumy];["&[@ColumnFromMyCurrentTable]&"]]"`

Any ideas how can I overcome this issue?

Comment: Is it possible to reconstruct things so that `INDIRECT` is not required?  Or construct a table of references in the different possible languages, and index into the proper reference?

Comment: @RonRosenfeld How do I get current language then?

Comment: You can use either `VBA` or `XLM4 macro` (stored as a formula defined name) to obtain both the country version of Excel, and also the country settings in Windows Regional settings.  You will not be able to save the file as `xlsx` -- you will need to use `xls`, `xlsm`, or `xlsb`.  It would be simpler if you didn't use `INDIRECT` at all.  The formulas should then translate themselves.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I'm not saying `INDIRECT` is the way to go. Couldn't find a better way to reference named table's column dynamically, though

Comment: I don't have a setup to evaluate that.  I am surprised that you can't just use the column names in the structured references, though.  I wouldn't expect those to change by country.  But I don't know about the row names.  I would hope they would change in the formula, but from what you write, I guess they don't.  In  any event, in my previous comment, I wrote about how to detect the country information.

Answer (score 1):

If there is no VBA involved, then a simple `IFERROR()` should do:

```
=IFERROR(
    INDIRECT("Attendees[[#Totals];["&[@ColumnFromMyCurrentTable]&"]]"),
    INDIRECT("Attendees[[#Sumy];["&[@ColumnFromMyCurrentTable]&"]]")
)
```

Comment: yeah, but this limits me only to languages that I do support, can you think of any options that are generic?

Comment: @SOReader - without VBA?

Comment: Theoretically, there should be a way - see the comment of @Ron Rosenfeld below your question.